# Arithmetic difficulty

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The sum of two people's age is 52.

8 years ago, one person was eight times as old as the other person.

Provide two equations showing this and solve for both people's age.

Comment: This looks like it might be a homework question. Can you provide us with where you are getting stuck and what steps you have taken so far?

Comment: So far, I have written down the following: x+y=52, (x-8)+8(x-8)=52 but it keeps failing to work out well. I know that once I get the second equation right, I will be fine, but I am having trouble figuring out what it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Start by designating $x:$ person one's age now, and $y:$ person two's age now.

Then the most obvious equation to start with is $$x + y = 52\tag{1}$$

Let person one be the person that was $8$ times as old as the other person, 8 years ago.

So $8$ years ago, person one's age was $(x-8)$. Eight years ago, person two's age was $(y - 8)$. Now, we know the age of person one eight years ago, was $8 \times $ the age of person two eight years ago. Thus, $$(x - 8)\;\text{ was equal to }\; 8 \times (y - 8)\tag{2}$$ This will form your second equation.

Now, you'll have two equations, with two unknowns, and can solve accordingly. Suggestion: from equation $(1)$, express $y$ in terms of $x$: $\;y = 52-x$, and substitute this for $y$ in equation $(2)$. Then solve for $x$, and then solve for $y = 52 - x$.

Comment: What would the end of the second equation be equal to? (x-8)+8(y-8)=(52-16)?

Comment: No, the second equation would simply be $(x - 8) = 8(y - 8)$. Then you'd have two equations: $x + y = 52$, and $(x - 8) = 8(y - 8)$. From the first equation, we know $y = 52 - x$. So that gives us $$(x - 8) = 8(\underbrace{52 - x}_{\large =\;y} - 8).$$ Now solve for $x$, and then back substitute that solution to solve $y = 52 - x$.

Comment: @Roy It is customary, or at least encouraged, for users to accept an answer to the questions they ask. To accept an answer (you can only accept one answer per question, but you can upvote as many answers as you find helpful) just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It changes from grey to green when you click on it. And you get $2$ reputation points for every question that you accept an answer to! ;-)